# intent on kotlin on android studio not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

i was working on a demo for kotlin app and separately these activities work but when i tried to link them up with intent ntn is responding to the button that was supposed to send u to the next activity it just doesnt do anyting and on the logcat there is no error showing just the info on where the screen touched so pls i still cant see where the problem lies after trying up all day

```
    package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

val tost:Button =findViewById(R.id.toast)
val nxt:Button =findViewById(R.id.next)
        tost.setOnClickListener{tst()}
        nxt.setOnClickListener{tnxt()}
        }
    private fun tst(){
        Toast.makeText(this,"hello world",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    private fun tnxt(){
          Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    
}
```

//and the diceroll class

```
package com.example.myapplication


import android.content.Intent

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dice_roll.*

class diceRoll : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dice_roll)

   var bttn:Button =findViewById(R.id.button)

        bttn.setOnClickListener {
           rolled()
        }
    }
    private fun rolled(){
        var txt:TextView=findViewById(R.id.no)
        val randomInt=(1..6).random()
        val resultStr=randomInt.toString()
        txt.setText(resultStr)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Change your function from

```
private fun tnxt(){
      Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

to:

```
private fun tnxt(){
    startActivity(Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java))
}
```

**The problem:**

With this line `Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java)`  you're creating an `Intent` but never use it.

```
private fun tnxt(){
    Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Alternatively,

```
private fun tnxt(){
    val diceRollIntent = Intent(this, diceRoll::class.java) //assigns the intent to a variable which we can use
    startActivity(diceRollIntent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue. checked the logcat.

My SecondActivity was trying to use some features from the AppCompat library, but the theme set for this activity in my application didn't inherit from Theme.AppCompat.

So, I went to `themes.xml` and changed the style to inherit from AppCompat.

```
  <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```